# MsgBox Not Showing when using barcode scanner

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I try to Show a simple message on texbox_texchanged event.
Why MsgBox is not showing in this case?

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        MsgBox("Hello") ' Showing
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        If TextBox1.Text.Length = 13 Then
            MsgBox("coucou") ' Not showing
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Because TextBox1.Text.Length is different than 13?

Comment: lol no i checked this, i think it's because i'm using a barcode scanner
If i'm using the keyborad, i have the message, not by using the scanner... very strange ....

Comment: I am completely sure that this is the reason. Bear in mind that TextChanged is called every time a char is inputted (e.g., 13 times before meeting the condition by typing manually). Please, provide code (= with inputs) which anyone can validate. Your code is fine; your inputs + the way in which you are using it is most likely wrong. Textbox1.Text has to have an exact length of 13 characters (including blank spaces -> it is usually recommendable to add a Trim() call just in case).

Comment: The barcode scanner is recognized by computer as an input peripherical like keyborad. I discovered that the string sended by the scanner contain a break line, so the string is like: 3463521331072\n

Comment: See? TextBox1.Text.Length is actually different than 13. You can enhance your code with Trim() + Replace to account for the break line (or any other problem)

Comment: The breakline is not considered as a textChanged event, i think i should use different method to capture the scanner input

Comment: ?! Might I know why you think such a thing? Some characters should not be considered characters because you don't like them or why? Additionally, how is your scanbar software working exactly? It delivers the whole text in one go or character by character? Seriously, what are you trying to prove? that your wrong approach is actually right and that whole world around it is wrong (and thus the question you are asking is unsolvable)?!

Comment: Input from barcode scanners is sometimes challenging to work with, I don't have one handy to test with but when I recently created a app for one I did hit a few challenges, I would recommend experimenting with the different events available on a textbox I am sure you will find one that fires with the barcode input, You may also be able to program the scanner to not include the break line?

Comment: Thank you, i'll test all the possibilities offered by text events i use the better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> so the string is like: 3463521331072\n

Not taking advantage of the \n character that the scanner sends is a mistake.  It is a very reliable end-of-input indicator.  It isn't very clear why you documented it in C# notation when you tagged with [vb.net].  So I'll ignore it, use the textbox' KeyDown event to detect it:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyData = Keys.Enter Then
        ProcessInput(TextBox1.Text)
        TextBox1.SelectAll()
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Note the ProcessInput() method you have to add to process the scanned string.  And note how SelectAll() is very important, it ensures that the *next* scanned data replaces the text.  You could also consider TextBox1.Text = String.Empty, that's safer, but then you have to display the scanned string somewhere else, like a Label.  You also have to make sure that the textbox always has the focus so the string ends up into that control, use its Focus() method when necessary.

Comment: Brilliant, wish i had thought of this a few month back - would have saved me a lot of time.

Comment: @OSKM Without underpraising Hans's suggestion, note that this kind of approach is not required to deal with this problem at all (i.e., you should be able to deal with scanner inputs exactly the same than with any other kind of inputs). When implementing any code, understanding the input structure properly is a basic requirement; the original code was relying on an arbitrary length without taking care of any other issue (like blank spaces, line breaks or any other thing). It was a bad code which wasn't ever debugged properly. Building such a code shouldn't ever be done.

Comment: @Hans Passant, perfect solution. I could consider using a label instead of textbox and capture the keyDown/Up events to populate it and ensure that user will not modify the content.

Comment: No, you cannot use Label for input, only for display.  It won't take the focus so its keyboard events never fire.  Also the basic reason why these events are hidden in the Properties window.

Comment: @varocarbas, you should take a herbal tea. it would calm you ;-)

Comment: @ebelair (sorry but I don't drink tea) I am very calmed. The aggressive attitude has nothing to do with my lack of calm, but with trying to transmit (in principle simple) ideas to persons who don't seem to understand them in other way (you know... I have done lots of trial-and-error tests lately and I think that this is the best approach; have been dealing with lots of people with limited understanding capabilities).

Comment: @HansPassant, i saw that cause i found this usefull example : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/296533/Using-a-bar-code-scanner-in-NET
If i not made a mistake, it's using the main window events

Comment: That can work if your window doesn't have any controls that can take the focus.  The form is then forced to take it.  Okay if you make it very modal, switching your UI into "ready to receive" mode with ShowDialog().  But you can't use, say, a OK or Close button, that doesn't score any usability points.  Using the KeyDown event is however a drastic mistake, you never want to get in the business have having to translate virtual keys to characters.  Keyboard layouts are not created equal.  You must use KeyPress instead.